# Behavior of Oracle's oci_execute() using OCI_DEFAULT for PHP > 5.3.2

Tags: php, oracle

I've come across some legacy code using Oracle's `oci_execute()` with `OCI_DEFAULT` flag.

```
oci_execute($this->result, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

However, this server now runs PHP > 5.3.2. According to the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php) for `OCI_DEFAULT`:

> Obsolete as of PHP 5.3.2 (PECL OCI8 1.4) but still available for backward compatibility. Use the equivalent OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT in new code.

So my question is two part:

- What did `OCI_DEFAULT` represent for PHP < 5.3.2?
- What is the effective mode when using `OCI_DEFAULT` in PHP >= 5.3.2? (i.e. the code above)

In attempts to answer part 2, I was hoping to find `oci_execute_mode()` for debugging. However, AFAIK such functions do not exist. From running the script it appears it commits on successful PHP script end (i.e. when the connection is closed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What did OCI_DEFAULT represent for PHP < 5.3.2?

The docs answer your first question.

> Obsolete as of PHP 5.3.2 (PECL OCI8 1.4) but still available for backward compatibility. Use the equivalent OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT in new code.

Then if you look for **OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT**...

> Do not automatically commit changes. Prior to PHP 5.3.2 (PECL OCI8 1.4) use OCI_DEFAULT which is an alias for OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT.

Short answer: "OCI_DEFAULT < PHP 5.3.2" = "same as OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT >= PHP 5.3.2" = "Don't automatically commit the statement being executed right now."

> What is the effective mode when using OCI_DEFAULT in PHP >= 5.3.2? (i.e. the code above)

It does the same thing as it did in < 5.3.2 to preserve backwards compatibility - it's just obsolete/deprecated now. You can use either OCI_DEFAULT or OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT, but you should use the latter because it may not be around forever.

Comment: Thanks. I figured so, but needed a sanity check. Part of me thought since `OCI_DEFAULT` was obsolete, it held no value, and therefore the function default (`OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS`) was used. However, additional tests showed otherwise.

Comment: I had to read it twice myself to be sure. I think it should really say "deprecated" instead of "obsolete".

Answer (score 0):

Web server should commit automatically without waiting for COMMIT command manually or automatically. If you want to process any transaction with group of inter-dependent SQL queries, I believe it is better idea to process those SQL queries in business layer or Stored Procedure in where COMMIT or ROLLBACK can be applied if necessary.

**Edit:**

What did OCI_DEFAULT represent for PHP < 5.3.2?

OCI_DEFAULT would automatically roll back when you close the connection. You needed to explicitly call oci_commit() to commit the transaction.

What is the effective mode when using OCI_DEFAULT in PHP >= 5.3.2?

Previous versions would have only OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS and OCI_DEFAULT. In new version, OCI_DEFAULT is just an alias for OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT. Previously, OCI_DEFAULT would make confusion about its purpose. OCI8 1.4 has added new mode OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT by renaming OCI_DEFAULT. There is no internal performance difference between OCI_DEFAULT and OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT.

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't answer either of my questions. You've told me about transactions and about `OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS` from the PHP docs.

Comment: What did OCI_DEFAULT represent for PHP < 5.3.2? OCI_DEFAULT would automatically roll back when you close the connection.

Comment: What is the effective mode when using OCI_DEFAULT in PHP >= 5.3.2? Probably, previous versions would have only OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS and OCI_DEFAULT. In new version, OCI_DEFAULT is just an alias for OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT. OCI_DEFAULT would make confusion about it purpose. I guess OCI8 1.4 has added new mode OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT for just renaming OCI_DEFAULT. I believe there is no internal performance difference between OCI_DEFAULT and OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT.

Comment: I have strange situation during refactoring old php 5.2 app to php 7.4. Even when using OCI_DEFAULT in both case on php 5.2 TRX is commited automatically but on php 7.4 is not commited. Same code. Defaults php, nothing special.