# Doctrine2: How to change from MySQL to Oracle database

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Initially, I started to develop a web application using Zend Framework 2 and  Doctrine2 with MySQL but the customer wants that the database would be Oracle. So, I have to change the database from MySQL to Oracle.

To do that, I have modified my **doctrine.local.php** file from this version

```
return array(
'doctrine' => array(
    'connection' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'driverClass' =>'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
            'params' => array(
                'host'     => 'localhost',
                'port'     => '3306',
                'user'     => 'user_gnsys',
                'password' => '******',
                'dbname'   => 'gnsys',
            ),
            'doctrine_type_mappings'  =>  array(
                    'enum'=>'string'
            )                   
        ),          
    )
  )
);
```

To this other version ...

```
return array(
'doctrine' => array(
    'connection' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                        'host' => 'localhost',
                        'port' => '1521',
                        'dbname' => 'GNSYS',
                        'driver' => 'oci8',
                        'user'  =>  'c##gnsys',
                        'password'  =>  '********',
                        'servicename' => 'demo31',
                ),
                'doctrine_type_mappings'  =>  array(
                        'enum'=>'string'
                )                   
        ),              
    )
  )
);
```

Next, I try to validate my schema using the next command:

```
josecarlos@R2D2:~/Workspace/Web/gnsys$ php public/index.php orm:validate-schema
```

And I've got the next exit ...

[image]

How can I remove all these "Notice" that I've got on the exit? Have I forget to update another file?

Comment: [This is related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281400/behavior-of-oracles-oci-execute-using-oci-default-for-php-5-3-2#answer-14282370) looks like the PHP constant was removed/changed. Also make sure you [have correctly configured PHP to use OCI8](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem installing oci8 library.